# How to change a value in a vector based on a value in another vector in r

Tags: r, vector

I would like to set values to zero in a vector if there are not equal to values from an other vector in ,3 and  ,4. For instances:

```
x = [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

y =  [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,] 0.35146459   8167  4  5
[2,] 0.01886205  24571  7  9
[3,] 0.32501692  73776  12  14
```

As result I would like to have this vector

```
z = [1] 0 0 4 5 0 7 8 9 0 0 12 13 14
```

Any tips how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: What languague you need it?

Comment: Why are the numbers 8 and 13 included in your desires output? They don't appear in columns 3 and 4 of your matrix

Comment: I work in r. ,3 and ,4 means column 3 and 4 of vector y

Comment: Its a range defined by column 3 and 4.

Comment: don't no what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we want to get the sequence between each row of the 3rd and 4th column, check whether those values are in 'x' and if it is not present, replace it with '0', one possible option is

```
(x %in% unlist(Map(`:`, y[,3], y[,4])))*x
#[1]  0  0  4  5  0  7  8  9  0  0 12 13 14
```

---

Just splitting the above solution for easier understanding.  Here, we use `Map` to get the sequence between each element of the 3rd and 4th column of 'y'.  The output is a `list`.

```
 Map(`:`, y[,3], y[,4])
 #[[1]]
 #[1] 4 5

 #[[2]]
 #[1] 7 8 9

 #[[3]]
 #[1] 12 13 14
```

Now, we `unlist` it to make a `vector`

```
 unlist(Map(`:`, y[,3], y[,4]))
 #[1]  4  5  7  8  9 12 13 14
```

The next step is checking whether the above values are found in 'x' or not.  For that we use `%in%`.  The output is a logical vector of 'TRUE/FALSE' based on whether the 'x' element is found in the above vector output or not.

```
 x %in%  unlist(Map(`:`, y[,3], y[,4]))
 #[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 #[13]  TRUE
```

In the last step, we multiply (`*`) the logical vector with 'x' values so that the logical vector gets coerced to integer representation i.e. `TRUE/FALSE` converts to `1/0` and `0*any number = 0` and `1* any number = any number`, we get

```
 (x %in% unlist(Map(`:`, y[,3], y[,4])))*x
 #[1]  0  0  4  5  0  7  8  9  0  0 12 13 14
```

#### data

```
x <- 2:14
y <- matrix(c(0.35146, 0.0188, 0.325, 8167, 24571, 73776, 4,7, 12, 
  5, 9, 14), ncol=4)
```

Comment: This *has* to be it. Pretty wicked solution, IMO.

Comment: wouldn't it be good to use `mapply` instead of `Map`. If not, please explain. Also, is multiplication(last step) more efficient than indexing as it is done in the other answer?

Comment: @Saksham `Map` is just a wrapper for `mapply`.  If you use `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` , it is `Map`.  Regarding the `lapply` vs `mapply`, both are loops, so I don't see much difference between that step, then we have the common `unlist`.  I think `*` would be faster (not tested though.  Also, this is not changing the original `x` object if you want to keep the original.

Comment: @Saksham In addition, `Map` always returns a `list`, while `mapply` without setting `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` (as it is TRUE by default), can get a `matrix` output if the lengths of the list elements are the same, or else a `list`.  So, the expected output is more consistent

Answer (score 2):

Less elegant than @akrun's solution, but since I had started working on it I might as well post this alternative version:

```
x[!(x %in% unlist(lapply(1:nrow(y), function(z) seq(y[z,3],y[z,4]))))] <- 0
> x
#[1]  0  0  4  5  0  7  8  9  0  0 12 13 14
```

Comment: Thanks, its very good alternative version